# Write and read from some file

Tags: c, file, fopen

I have a similar code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE* file = fopen("file.txt", "w+");
  fputc('A', file);
  fflush(file);
  char buff;
  fscanf(file, "%s", &buff);
  printf("read data: %s", &buff);
  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```

I want without close file read written data. But in buff not exist data. 
Why?
If i close file after writing and then read all worked.

Comment: You have to seek back to where the data is available to be read.  Or rewind the file after writing.

Comment: And not use `%s` to read into, or `printf()` from, a single `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `rewind(file)` to set the position indicator associated with the file stream to the beginning of the file.

Your example, working fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE* file = fopen("file.txt", "w+");
  fputc('A', file);
  fflush(file);
  rewind (file);
  char buff [80];
  fscanf(file, "%s", buff);
  printf("read data: %s", buff);
  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rewind back to the beginning of the file:

```
rewind(file);
```